# some questions about channel of golang

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm watching a video on YouTube which is talking about concurrency patterns.
There is a ping-pong example:

```
type Ball struct{ hits int }
func main() {
    table := make(chan *Ball)
    go player("ping", table)
    go player("pong", table)

    table <- new(Ball)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    <-table
}

func player(name string, table chan *Ball) {
    for {
        ball := <-table
        ball.hits++
        fmt.Println(name, ball.hits)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        table <- ball
    }
}
```

Which should gives the result:

```
Ping 1
Pong 2
Ping 3
Pong 4
...
```

However, if I remove one goroutine of player, "pong" for example:

```
// go player("pong", table) // remove this line
```

I got only one result:

```
Ping 1
```

I don't understand there is a for loop in the func player, and 'table' channel gives the Ball out to ball, at the end of loop, we put the Ball back to the channel table. Why the player "ping" can't player with himself?

Comment: Maybe try the "Tour of Go" first, this is covered in the section on concurrency: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

Answer (score 6):

The channel is unbuffered, meaning one routine must receive in order for the other routine's send to complete. If you remove the `pong` player, the `ping` player is blocked sending on the channel (`pong` is not there to receive), so it will never move to the next iteration of the loop to receive its own message.

If you were to make the channel buffered, the send would be non-blocking if there is room in the buffer: `table := make(chan *Ball, 1)`. This would allow one ball to be "held" in the channel's buffer until a receiver is ready.